# ORA-00054 error in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I am getting the above error :

```
ORA-00054 error in SQL "Resource busy and acquire with NOWAT specified or timeout expired"
```

When i try and run the following command:

```
CREATE TABLE CONFERENCESESSION (
SESSIONID CHAR(4) NOT NULL,
BUILDINGNO CHAR(2),
ROOMNO CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
SPEAKERID CHAR(2),
SESSIONDATE DATE,
SESSIONPRICE NUMBER(4,2),
CONSTRAINT SESSIONID_PK PRIMARY KEY(SESSIONID),
CONSTRAINT BUILDINGNO_FK1 FOREIGN KEY (BUILDINGNO) REFERENCES BUILDING(BUILDINGNO),
CONSTRAINT ROOMNO_FK2 FOREIGN KEY (ROOMNO,BUILDINGNO) REFERENCES ROOM(ROOMNO,BUILDINGNO),
CONSTRAINT SPEAKERID_FK3 FOREIGN KEY (SPEAKERID) REFERENCES SPEAKER(SPEAKERID)
);
```

I am unsure how to find what is using the object.

I am using Oracle SQL developer for a school assignment.

Comment: No error message?

Comment: please edit the title, also :)

Comment: Unrelated, but: the `char` data type is almost always a bad decision. `varchar2` is the recommended type for character data

Answer (score 0):

That error is normally caused by locking, try breaking up you create table query, like:

```
CREATE TABLE CONFERENCESESSION (
SESSIONID CHAR(4) NOT NULL,
BUILDINGNO CHAR(2),
ROOMNO CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
SPEAKERID CHAR(2),
SESSIONDATE DATE,
SESSIONPRICE NUMBER(4,2)
)
GO

ALTER TABLE CONFERENCESESSION ADD CONSTRAINT SESSIONID_PK PRIMARY KEY(SESSIONID)
GO
ALTER TABLE CONFERENCESESSION ADD CONSTRAINT BUILDINGNO_FK1 FOREIGN KEY (BUILDINGNO) REFERENCES BUILDING(BUILDINGNO)
GO
ALTER TABLE CONFERENCESESSION ADD CONSTRAINT ROOMNO_FK2 FOREIGN KEY (ROOMNO,BUILDINGNO) REFERENCES ROOM(ROOMNO,BUILDINGNO)
GO
ALTER TABLE CONFERENCESESSION ADD CONSTRAINT SPEAKERID_FK3 FOREIGN KEY (SPEAKERID) REFERENCES SPEAKER(SPEAKERID)
GO
```

Run each batch individually and you'll be able to isolate the part that is causing the error

Comment: Thanks, ive done what you said and the 2nd and 3rd ALTER query's give me the same error, how should i go about this to fix it?

Comment: Is there an open transaction on the two tables they are referencing? I would suspect that the columns that you are trying to add the constraint on in the `BUILDING` and `ROOM` table are being used

Comment: I did some googling on how to find out if there are open transactions and ran this command "SELECT * FROM sys.sysprocesses WHERE open_tran = 1;" (Not sure how to format to code in comments) and it says the table doesnt exist?

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan I am using my Uni's SQL connection and a friend who is doing the same assignment says its fine for him. Can i do anything on my end?

Comment: Have a look at, `v$transaction`, `v$session` & `v$mystat`

Comment: So do you have your own schema?

Comment: Or is there a way i can use a local connection?

Comment: @APC im not 100% sure what a schema is, but every student in my course connects to the uni with his/her own account.

Comment: A schema is the set of objects owned by a user. So, yes, you have your own schema. That makes life easier. Those foreign keys reference your own tables. So the blocking session is one of yours. Do you have more than one session running? If you're using a tool like SQL Developer then it may be configured to have a separate session for each worksheet tab.

Comment: I dont currently have any other worksheets open but i did before, is that an issue?

Comment: @TimothyBolton, are you able to termination all other open connections to the DB and then try again?

Answer (score 0):

you may use this query to detect who's locking your table:

```
select distinct s.inst_id, s.sid, s.serial#, s.module, s.client_info, s.username, s.status, s.osuser, o.object_name
from gv$session s, gv$locked_object l, dba_objects o 
where l.object_id = o.object_id 
  and l.session_id = s.sid 
  and l.inst_id = s.inst_id
  and lower(o.object_name) like lower('%'||'&i_table_name'||'%') 
--and lower(s.module) like lower('%'||'&i_modul_name'||'%')  
--and s.username = upper('&i_schema_name')
order by o.object_name
```

if you have db privileges.

Comment: What is "Modul_Name"?

Comment: @TimothyBolton as an alternative you may use to filter if `dbms_application_info.set_module` is used to set. But, for now `&i_table_name` is our case. It's already commented out.

Answer (score 0):

FIXED, I can delete current sessions through my uni website.

Comment: then, dml locks on those tables are released.